# WINSCP script stop working after password change for FTP

Tags: winscp

I have a batch script that has been working for many months now and we have been changing password without issue before. But I noticed since we changed password last week the files are no longer transfered. I checked the firewall and the settingsand everything seems fine. The problem is replicated everywhere when using another machines. Please see the log file from winscp below . The password and the user does not even have special characters.

```
WinSCP Version 5.9.3 (Build 7136) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Enterprise)
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Configuration: C:\Program Files\winSCP\WinSCP.ini
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Log level: Normal
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Local account: xxxxxxxxxxxx
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Working directory: C:\Program Files\WinSCP
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Process ID: 7804
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Command-line: "C:\Program Files\winSCP\WinSCP.exe"   /script=xxxxxxxxxxxxhealth.txt /log=c:log_winscp.txt  
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Time zone: Current: GMT+1 
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Login time: Tuesday, August 22, 2017 9:00:24 AM
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: option batch continue
< 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: batch           continue  
< 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: option confirm off
< 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: confirm         off       
> 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: reconnecttime 900
< 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: Unknown command 'reconnecttime'.
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: Failed
> 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Script: open ftp://company:***@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Session name: company@xxxxxxxxxx.com (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Host name: xxxxxxxxxx.com (Port: 21)
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 User name: company (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 6000 sec
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Disable Nagle: No
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Proxy: None
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.720 Send buffer: 262144
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 UTF: Auto
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 FTPS: None [Client certificate: No]
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 Local directory: C:\, Remote directory: /, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-08-22 09:00:24.730 Connecting to xxxxxxxxxx.com ...
. 2017-08-22 09:00:25.660 Connected with xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com. Waiting for welcome message...
< 2017-08-22 09:00:25.990 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2017-08-22 09:00:25.990 USER company
< 2017-08-22 09:00:26.270 331 Password required for company.
> 2017-08-22 09:00:26.270 PASS **********
< 2017-08-22 09:00:26.550 530 User company cannot log in.
. 2017-08-22 09:00:26.550 Connection failed.
. 2017-08-22 09:00:26.550 Password prompt (last login attempt failed)
```

Comment: Read tag description! `BATCH-FILE` **DOES NOT mean processing multiple files!**

Comment: Thanks Steve. I have changed the tag. However, the winscp still run from batch file.

Comment: Ohh.. you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Is there some special character in the new password?

Comment: No there is no special character. It only contain leters and a number

Comment: Martin, And also when I used winscp.com the error is authentication failed access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. The password does not like number at the end of the password and even though GUI accepted the password. I made sure that the password is not similar in name to the previous one.

Thanks Martin for your support